# How to add required validation on both value and text field of a dropdown in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-validators

In below angular-2 code I am using a dropdown inside a form which is required field , if i use the validation on the value field of the dropdown it works fine but i want the value and text both should not be null or empty, how can i add the required validation on text of a drop also.

HTML

```
<select formControlName="PayPeriodId" placeholder="Pay Period" required>
<option *ngFor="let PayPeriod of payPeriodList" [value]="PayPeriod.Id">
        {{PayPeriod.Name}}
      </option>
    </select>
```

Component

```
let employeePersonalDetail : new PersonalDetailResponseModel();
 this.editEmployeeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  PayPeriodId: [employeePersonalDetail.PayPeriodId, Validators.required]
});
```

Comment: In a "dropdown" (`<select>` element) , you are in charge of the text displayed. Why do you display `<option>` without text if you don't want it ?

Comment: actually  the payperiod gets expired after an interval of time so the when i open the form in edit mode the value field of a dropdown contains a value but text field does not so the validation does not work.

Comment: The problem is, if your time is expired you shouldn't display elements, or you should add a validator that verifies the time is not expired..?

Comment: You could read the docs https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation

Comment: @Florian we don't display the expired element in dropdown but its id remain in employee table which gets bind in value of payperiod field of dropdown.

Comment: @MohanSingh create a `BehaviorSubject` (example : `payPeriodList$`), when you receive data from your service, you notify observers `payPeriodList$.next(res)`. When you timeout, you notify observers `payPeriodList$.next([])`.
In your template, you modify your option : `*ngFor="let PayPeriod of payPeriodList$ | async"`.

Comment: Will try this @Florian